# SQL: how do i order by a field if its not null else use another field

Tags: sql, mysql

i want to sort my `Posts` by `dtModified` (datetime modified) if its not null (post modified b4), else sort by `dtPosted` (datetime posted)

Comment: Sort in which order? Ascending or descending?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like I'm giving this advice three times a week here on SO, maybe I should just give up and let it go :-) Nah, I don't think so:

*Don't* use per-row functions in your column calculations (or `order by` clauses) if you want your database to scale well. You should check performance for your particular case (*measure, don't guess*) but doing calculations when *reading* the database will generally affect your ability to scale (this won't matter for your address book database but the shops I work in have *huge* amounts of data).

The number of "how do I get my DB to go faster?" questions far outweighs the number of "how do I use less space?" ones. It's a well-trodden path to sacrifice disk space for performance.

The right time to do calculations is when the data changes. That way the cost of the changes is amortised across all reads.

My advice is to create another column such as `dtLastAction` to contain the ordering value then use an insert/update trigger to set it to the same as `dtModified` if not null, or `dtPosted` if `dtModified` is null. Technically, this violates 3NF but that's okay if you know what you're doing, and the triggers guarantee data consistency in that case.

Then index on the `dtLastAction` column and see the speed of your queries improve at the (lesser) cost of some extra work during inserts and updates. I say lesser because the *vast* majority of database tables are read more often than written (obviously this method is useless if your particular situation is one of the very rare exceptions).

Alternatively, for this particular case, you could set `dtModified` and `dtPosted` to the same value when creating the entry, meaning that `dtModified` will never *be* null. You can still detect posts that have never been modified by the fact that these two datetime values are identical.

Comment: yes, i think `dtLastAction` is great. maybe checking if checking if `dtModified` is same as `dtPosted` is an even greater. i dont need 1 extra field. maybe rename `dtModified` to `dtLastAction` will make it more intuitive

Comment: Overall I agree with lowering the cost of reads. However, this particular case is so simple I don't think it justifies all the added complexity of caching. E.g. if the action gets deleted then you then need to update the last action date to the remaining latest action, nightmare!

Answer (score 25):

You can use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(dtModified, dtPosted)
```

Another option is to use the MySQL specific function [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) instead of `COALESCE`.

---

Testing on MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (dtModified DATETIME NULL, dtPosted DATETIME NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 (dtModified, dtPosted) VALUES
('2010-07-31 10:00:00', '2010-07-30 10:00:00'),
(NULL                 , '2010-07-31 09:00:00'),
('2010-07-31 08:00:00', '2010-07-30 10:00:00');

SELECT dtModified, dtPosted
FROM table1
ORDER BY COALESCE(dtModified, dtPosted)
```

Results:

```
dtModified           dtPosted
2010-07-31 08:00:00  2010-07-30 10:00:00
NULL                 2010-07-31 09:00:00
2010-07-31 10:00:00  2010-07-30 10:00:00
```

Comment: can you use a COALESCE in an ORDER BY?

Comment: Yes, I think you have to use `IFNULL` for MySQL.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo: I just tested it in MySQL and it seems to work fine. See my updated answer for the SQL I used.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Works fine ... I think copy/pasted your previous typo in `COALESCE` :)

Comment: This is a neat trick and demonstrates the advantage of ordering on dates rather than on ids

Answer (score 1):

In your SELECT, use a CASE statement that takes the value of date modified if not null otherwise date posted. Then use that new "calculated" columnn for your ORDER BY.