# MySQL - Order by column 1 but column 2 if not null

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I've tried to order some results in MySQL but I'm not sure what I want is doable with a single order by

```
drop temporary table if exists temp;  

create temporary table temp (  
  doc integer not null,  
  dest integer null  
);  

insert into temp  
(doc, dest)  
values  
(1, 0),  
(2, 0),  
(3, 100000),  
(3, 142000),  
(4, 100000),  
(4, 142000),  
(5, 0),  
(6, 0),  
(7, 100000),  
(7, 142000),  
(8, 100000),  
(8, 142000),  
(9, 100000),  
(9, 142000);
```

I'd like to order this by doc, but when dest is not null by dest then doc instead of doc.
That would give :

```
(1, 0)  
(2, 0)  
(3, 100000)  
(4, 100000)  
(3, 142000)  
(4, 142000)  
(5, 0)  
(6, 0)  
(7, 100000)  
(8, 100000)  
(9, 100000)  
(7, 142000)  
(8, 142000)  
(9, 142000)
```

Thanks for any help.

Regards,

Greg

Comment: can you include the case when data in a row is (3, null) (4, null)

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure to understand your question. If you mean what happens where there is a dest = 0 value for a doc that also has dest != 0 values, it cannot happen.

Comment: What I meant was what will your output look like when dest is null. what will output look for (10, null) (0,null)

Comment: also looks duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377854/sql-how-do-i-order-by-a-field-if-its-not-null-else-use-another-field

Comment: there is no null (or null is 0 in my case if you prefer)