# Elasticsearch sort by a field and use another field if its null

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have `Post` model with `lastRepliedTime` and `createdTime` attributes. How can I sort this `Post` by `lastRepliedTime`, but when its value is null, I use `createdTime` as sort value?

For example, I have this data:

```
ID  createdTime          lastRepliedTime
1   2015-05-27 13:48:10  2015-06-04 16:34:43
2   2015-06-09 05:23:38  2015-06-24 00:30:06
3   2015-06-09 17:34:56  NULL
```

If I sort by ascending order, I want the sort result to be like this:

```
ID  createdTime          lastRepliedTime
1   2015-05-27 13:48:10  2015-06-04 16:34:43
3   2015-06-09 17:34:56  NULL
2   2015-06-09 05:23:38  2015-06-24 00:30:06
```

I've found the solution using MySQL in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377854/sql-how-do-i-order-by-a-field-if-its-not-null-else-use-another-field). But is there any way to sort it using Elasticsearch?

Comment: Hey, were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try ?

```
{
    "sort": [
        { "lastRepliedTime": { "order": "asc" }},
        { "createdTime": { "order": "asc" }}
    ],
    "query" : {
       "match_all" : { }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't give the result that I want. I've updated the question with an example. Thank you.

Comment: @rap13 were you able to find a solution to this?